# How to use Cassandra in the Dropwizard

Tags: java, cassandra, dropwizard

I tried to migrate the springboot application to the Dropwizard. However, I now have a problem that there is no framework in the Dropwizard that supports working with Cassandra databases, such as CRUD operations. Do any of you have any good suggestions?

Comment: Just use DataStax Java driver: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/

Comment: You can use Spring at the service layer with Dropwizard